# React Native Application has not been registered {[React native]}

Tags: javascript

I am also having the same issue and I am using:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.4.1",
    "react-native": "0.55.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "5.0.2",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.4.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Can any one suggest any solution about this problem? I have spent 2 days on this issue and this does not seem to be going anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

i have found the solution t this problem and here is the package.json file it will help u guys alot and after pasting the file in your project directory go to cmd and write npn install

{
  "name": "Test2",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.3.0-alpha.1",
    "react-native": "0.54.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^4.0.1",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.5.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}